# Getting an auto-incremented value from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a PHP script where data is inserted into a table using a query like "INSERT INTO y (x, x, x) VALUES (z, z, z). I have a unique, primary, auto-incrementing key that is in the table. How can I fetch that number right after the data is inserted and the key is updated with the new row?

Comment: 4 seconds in the manual or on google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

more information and example of use:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you are making the queries, if you are using some DB abstraction layer or not...

mysql functions: [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

mysqli: [mysqli->insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

PDO: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query